Proteus errors for PIC microcontroller mixed model PIC16.DLL failed to authorize
I am following a tutorial to turn on an LED by using interrupts. I feel like I have been following it exactly as provided in the video. The tutorial goes over how to use the demo version of proteus 8 to simulate a PIC microcontroller 16F877A to prototype the simple circuit. Here is the schematic I made on proteus:

I pressed the play button on the bottom left and got the following in the error log:
mixed model PIC16.DLL failed to authorize - Missing or invalid Customer Key.. [U1]
Real Time Simulation failed to start.
Simulation FAILED due to fatal simulator errors.

I loaded the HEX file into the PIC by double clicking the model and selecting the hex file produced by MPLABX projects. The code is verbatim what was in the video:
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming 
//Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage programming enabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code 
protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection 
//off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection 
//off)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
//#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000

void interrupt external(){

if(INTCONbits.INTF == 1){
    PORTCbits.RC0 = ~PORTCbits.RC0;
    INTCONbits.INTF = 0;
}
   
}

void main(void) {

INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;
INTCONbits.INTE = 1;

OPTION_REGbits.INTEDG = 1;
TRISC0 = 0;

while(1){
    
}


return;
}


It's a demo mode limitation. If you use the examples you can load your own code, but not change the parts.

If this is true, then you can't really test the PIC. Do you know of another way? I tried using the LCD example and it says i am not allowed to change the connectivity to the LCD. One of the pins being used is the INT pin which i need for the example in the youtube video.

I guess you could pay for the program. Most of us probably just build the circuit or use an eval board.

There are more PIC simulators, use your web search skills to find them, please. Only few of them are commercial and proprietary, some of them are even open source software.
